# copy Files from LocationB to LocationA only when Folders present

Tags: copy, xcopy

Hi Trying to do a Folder Migration on a server, But keeping it clean in the process. 
The new Folder Structure has the relevant Folders only. 
While the old Structure has every previous folder setup since the dawn of age

What am trying to do, is copy files from the old structure to the new structure only if the directory exists in the new structure.

Each User may have 3/4 different sub folders, But i only want the files to be copied in and no folders to be created. 
All the folders are the same name, just the Number changes i.e
User01 User02 User03 User04 etc
Then there is a set of Sub Directories

For example:

Old Structure: 
c:\oldserver\User99\SubFolder1  Subfolder2, SubFolder3 Subfolder4

New Structure
c:\NewServer\User99\Subfolder1 Subfolder4

Each folder including the sub contain files

The same rule applies for the Users, Old Structure has users from 01 - 700
While the new structure only has about 200 Users.

Or in a simple form, how to copy recursively without creating folders.

Answer (score 0):

i could not find any existing tools that allowed copying of files without creating a directory. it seems abit of a odd request.

So instead, what i did, was use powershell, to list the current NEW Directory structure, and then copy files from the old structure to the new

Here is a working example:

```
Foreach ($file in Get-Childitem "C:\NewServer\Clients") {
Copy-Item "C:\Backup\OldServer\$file\*" "C:\NewServer\Clients\$file" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Its not ideal, as there are subfolders within a Users Directory that are being created. Its something to work with at least